# Auto adjustable token supply

Tags: solidity, tokens, price

Is it possible to a token to adjust its own total supply so it can keep your price more stable?

I mean when a token "realizes" it is too cheap it burns some amount and when is too expensive it mint some amount.

I know a token ( a contract )  can interact with the Liquidity Pool so it can check its price (at least in theory).

is it worth doing this? it will make any real difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the token and its liquidity, the problem you may face is that you can't check all the places it's being traded at. Even if you check Uniswap, someone can just create another pool in another decentralized exchange - or even in Uniswap.

But burning and minting will not affect the price directly either. In the long run they should affect the price, but not immediately. So this also depends on the token's liquidity - if it's not being traded much, the effect will be very slow.

Otherwise, I guess you can try to check some pool about their reserves and mint/burn accordingly. Just be aware of various attack vectors this introduces: for example flash loans may skew the balance momentarily.

Comment: Enlightening. It makes sense. I hadn't thought about it. Thanks.

Comment: So how the people around created tokens they say "stable" or "FIAT-equivalent" like USDT and so?

Comment: Oh that's a whole other topic. Various approaches, for example algorithmic or asset-backed. Please post a new question or search for existing questions about the topic (there are quite many probably)

Comment: Uh! Too complex. Lets left it quiet. Many thanks!!